# nvd3 - how to disable tooltip in discrete bar chart

Tags: meteor, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 1.8.2, d3 3.5.8 and meteor 1.3.
I used the [example discreteBarChart from the nvd3 docs](http://nvd3.org/examples/discreteBar.html).
But when i try to disable the tooltips just like in the example with `chart.tooltips(false)` and i get a console error that says 'tooltip is not a function'.

I also tried `chart.tooltip.enabled(false)`, that does not work either.

See:

```
    // chart object
let chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.x
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.y
    })
    .staggerLabels(true)
    .showValues(false)
    .showYAxis(false)
    // .tooltips(false)
    .duration(250);

// chart details
nv.addGraph(function() {
    d3.select('#chartWordsAll svg')
      .datum(barChart())
      .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Any ideas how i can disable the tooltip?

Thanks in advance!

Muff

Comment: you need to show your code ...

Comment: perhaps a working jsfiddle. This just looks more or less the same as the link provided

Answer (score 1):

Since even `chart.tooltip.enabled(false)` didn't work as it shows in the [documentation](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#tooltip), you could try to use [angularjs-nvd3-directives](https://github.com/angularjs-nvd3-directives/angularjs-nvd3-directives) and set `tooltips=false` which seems to work well in this example:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xerwrzwm/

Comment: thanks for the hint - i'm using blaze for this project.